# Como faço para popular um JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Tenho uma aplicação em java bem simples, que conecta com um banco de dados, no console eu digito a query que desejo que é passada por parâmetro para o executeQuery. Agora preciso passar tudo isso para uma interface gráfica. Tem alguma forma de eu criar apenas uma janela, e passar os dados como estão dispostos para a interface gráfica?

Não tenho nada feito ainda, tenho uma JTable apenas declarada, pois não achei nenhum tutorial bom de como se fazer. No meu programa tenho um JTextArea que recebe uma query, ai precisarei mostrar dinâmicamente essa tabela assim que clicar no botão executar. Minha dúvida é como popular essa tabela.

Comment: Sim, é possível. Se for para aplicação desktop você pode usar tanto o swing como javafx. Qual é a sua dúvida exatamente?

Comment: Acho que me expressei mal, minha dúvida é como popular a tabela.

Comment: Você já uma tabela? Seria uma JTable? Poderia mostrar um pouco do seu código na parte em que você tem que popular essa tabela?

Comment: @math não tenho nada feito ainda, sim, tenho uma JTable apenas declarada, pois não achei nenhum tutorial bom de como se fazer. No meu programa tenho um JTextArea que recebe uma query, ai precisarei mostrar dinâmicamente essa tabela assim que clicar no botão executar.

Comment: Você está usando ResultSet para fazer a busca no BD?

Comment: Sim, estou usando ResultSet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para criar e popular uma JTable, você deve na verdade adicionar os dados em uma DefaultTableModel e então setá-la como o model da tabela.

Fiz um exemplo com comentários que segue abaixo:

```
JTable table = new JTable();
String[] nomesColunas = {"nome", "endereco", "telefone"};
//essa lista terá as linhas da sua JTable, preenchi abaixo apenas como exemplo
List<String[]> lista = new ArrayList<>();
//aqui você fará um while percorrendo seu result set e adicionando na lista
//while(resultset.next()) {
lista.add(new String[]{"Joao", "rua um", "1234-5678"});
lista.add(new String[]{"Henrique", "rua 42", "1122-3344"});
lista.add(new String[]{"Manuel", "av 7 de setembro", "8765-4321"});
//} //fim while
//crie um defaultablemodel com as informações acima
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
        lista.toArray(new String[lista.size()][]), nomesColunas);
//define o model da sua tabela
table.setModel(model);
//adiciona no contentpane, coloque dentro de um JScrollPane pois caso 
//contrário não aparecerão os nomes das colunas
contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Math, ta dando certo, mas uma dúvida, eu adiciono na lista um objeto de string né? Mas o resultSet me retorna um object, como faço?

Comment: @JoãoNeto Exempo: `lista.add(new String[]{String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("id")), resultSet.getString("nome"), String.valueOf(resultSet.getBoolean("cadastrado"))};` Ou seja, você pega o valor de acordo com o seu tipo, e especifique corretamente no nome do método, getString pega String, getInt pega Int. E tudo que não for String você converte com String.valueOf(). O argumento dentro do método getTipo() deve ser o nome da coluna no seu BD.

Comment: Valeu! Deu certo.