# Passando diferentes tipos de Objeto para um TableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Estou começando a mexer com a JTable mas estou com uma dúvida. Estou vendo esse [post aqui](http://www.guj.com.br/java/132698-jtable-removendo-colunas-em-tempo-de-execucao#714736) em um outro fórum e a minha dúvida é. No caso ele passa para o modelo da tabela uma lista do tipo livro:

```
private List<Livro> valores;         

public TitulosTableModel(List<Livro> valores) {  
      this.valores = new ArrayList<Livro>(valores);  
}
```

Mas no meu exemplo, eu tenho várias entidades (não to usando livro), aluno, professor, disciplina etc... Eu terei de fazer um table model para cada entidade, ou tem uma forma de fazer o table model genérico, para receber uma lista de qualquer tipo de objeto?

Comment: Acabei de lembrar que eu já tinha respondido algo parecido e por fim eu encontrei: [Como faço para popular um JTable?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20738/3117). Para minha surpresa você é o autor da outra pergunta também. Não seria isso o caso de uma duplicata? Se não for, por favor explique qual é a diferença pois agora eu fiquei confuso.

Comment: Não Math, como popular a tabela eu já sei, to usando o AbstractTableModel, e então no meu TableModel eu recebo uma Lista de Alunos, o que eu queria saber é se terei que criar um table model pra cada tipo: Lista de professores, lista de cursos... Ou se tem alguma forma de eu tratar isso dentro do mesmo TableModel.

Comment: Porque quando eu clicar em alunos, quero que apareça a lista dos alunos, quando clicar em professor a mesma coisa... Mas tudo usando a mesma TableModel.

Comment: Ok, entendi! Vou remover minha resposta por enquanto pois estou sem tempo para atualizar, se eu atualiza mais tarde eu desfaço a exclusão. Boa sorte.

Comment: Beleza! Valeu Math!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O projeto [BeanTableModel](https://beantablemodel.java.net/) existe com esse propósito. Se você precisar de *features* um pouco mais avançadas eu recomendo o projeto [Glazed Lists](http://www.glazedlists.com/) (esse além de ter um `TableModel` genérico e manter os elementos sincronizados entre a lista e a *UI*; também possuiu facilidades para ordenar e filtrar dados), ambos são projetos razoavelmente velhos mas quebram um galho.

```
final EventList<MeuPOJO> eventList = GlazedLists.eventList(minhaListaDePOJOS);
final TableFormat<MeuPOJO> tableFormat = GlazedLists.tableFormat(MeuPOJO.class,
        new String[]{"minhaPropriedade1", "minhaProriedade2"},
        new String[]{"minhaColuna1", "minhaColuna2"});
final AdvancedTableModel<MeuPojo> tableModel = GlazedListsSwing
        .eventTableModel(eventList, tableFormat);  
jTable.setModel(tableModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Já que você tem listas diferentes, você vai ter que criar um `TableModel` para cada uma. Ex: Uma para `List<Livro>`, uma para `List<Professores>`, uma para `List<Alunos>` e etc.

Como os seus Beans são diferentes, eles irão ter campos diferentes, portanto não podem partilhar dos mesmos métodos num `TableModel`.

Comment: Fiz dessa forma mesmo. Valeu.