# Como atualizar JTable usado dados de um banco de dados?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

Eu criei no NetBeans um sistema de cadastro de cliente e cadastro de filme (simulando uma locadora). Tenho 3 arquivos Java: Locadora (main), Cliente e Filme. Em Cliente e Filme, eu faço a conexão com o banco de dados, insiro os valores, tudo bonitinho. A questão é: Como fazer para, quando eu executar a aplicação, e acessar Cliente/Filme, a `JTable` se preencher com os dados do banco de dados pré-armazenados.

Por exemplo: Eu abro a aplicação, insiro uns dados (lembrando que o que aparece no `JTable` não provém do banco de dados, mas sim de um simples `getText()`), eles vão para o banco, e fecho a aplicação. Aí quando eu abro de novo, a `JTable` está vazia, embora os dados que inseri anteriormente estejam no banco. Eu quero uma forma de pegar os dados do banco e jogá-los no `JTable`, para mantê-lo atualizado.

Comment: Veja se a resposta [nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20738/4808) é o que está buscando.

Comment: Na verdade, eu não sei. Eu sou meio que novato, mas pelo que eu vi nessa pergunta, o cara já fez meio caminho do que eu queria fazer, que é fazer a busca, e lá ele está apenas tentando inserir. Mas eu não sei nem como buscar, e nem como inserir rsrs.

Comment: Você está usando AbstractTableModel?

Answer (score 0):

1) Você precisa criar um método que retorne a lista de elementos do banco de dados.
2) A JTable possui um TableModel, crie uma classe que extenda DefaultTableModel.
3) Crie um construtor que receba a lista de elementos e mapeie as linhas e colunas do TableModel.
4) Na sua aplicação, inicialize o seu tableModel passando a lista de dados do banco.
5) passe o model para a tabela -> table.setModel(seuModelo)

Veja essa [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67326/inserir-dados-numa-table-a-partir-de-um-formul%C3%A1rio-em-java-netbeanssql-server/70530#70530) com mais detalhes!