# Inserir dados numa table a partir de um formulário em Java (Netbeans+SQL Server)

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, jtable

Eu tenho um formulário criado de modo a puder inserir dados sobre um cliente e a partir desse formulário abrir com um botão uma tabela que tenha os dados, até agora já consegui fazer a ligação dos botões. Agora a minha dúvida é como é que consigo enviar os dados do form para a table... Não quero o código, só preciso que me expliquem como é que faço isso.

Comment: Voce quer enviar os dados do form pra tabela ou os dados do banco?

Comment: Não consegui entender a sua pergunta. Quando você se refere a "tabela"/"table", não é claro se você fala da JTable do swing ou de uma tabela no SQL Server.

Comment: Quero enviar os dados do form para a tabela e depois da tabela para a DB... 
Eu uso o netbeans e o sql server 2008

Comment: Pegue os dados dos `TextFields` e passe para uma `List` em seguida carregue essa `List` na sua tabela e no final da pra você criar um botão para salvar todos os dados da lista em seu banco.

Comment: Eu vou tentar fazer isso e depois posto a resposta aqui. Obrigado...
Eu ainda estou a aprender Java então é complicado

Comment: Tudo bem, se quiser algo mais especifico é só perguntar aqui que tento passar uma solução mais completa.

Comment: Eu entendo em teoria como é que tenho que fazer, mas não me pode dar um exemplo e explicar? Obrigado

Comment: @diiana bem vinda. Você tem dúvidas: "Como enviar os dados de um formulário para uma `JTable`?" e "Como enviar os dados de uma `JTable` para o banco de dados?". Uma sugestão é que você quebre essa pergunta em duas, da forma em que ela encontra-se no momento as respostas seriam amplas.

Comment: Obrigado :3 mas inicialmente quero só mesmo perceber como é que envio os dados do formulário para a Jtable..  @re22

Answer (score 2):

A JTable possui um Table Model... crie uma classe que extenda DefaultTableModel, e monte o seu modelo.. modifique o modelo, depois faça table.setModel(seuModelo)

Exemplo:

para uma classe com esses atributos

```
class Cliente{
   Integer id;
   String nome;
   //getters and setters
}
```

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
class ClienteTableModel extends DefaultTableModel{
     public ClienteTableModel(){
        this.addColumn("ID");
        this.addColumn("NOME");
     }

     public ClienteTableModel(List<Cliente> listClientes){
        this();
        for(Cliente c: listClientes){
            this.addRow(new String[]{c.getId(),c.getNome()});
        }
     }
}
```

Aí, em sua view, você faz assim:

```
List<Cliente> listClientes = buscaClientes();
ClienteTableModel model = new ClienteTableModel(listClientes);
table.setModel(model);
```

Comment: Como faz isso? Pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: Poste um exemplo para que seja mais fácil para o Autor da pergunta e outros membros entenderem.

Comment: Editei a resposta e coloquei um exemplo