# Como inserir título de colunas num jTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Não consegui exibir o título da tabela, poderiam ajudar?
Obs.: Inseri `"JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tabela);`" e "`contentPane.add(scroll);`" ou "`getContentPane.add(scroll)`" conforme vi em perguntas/respostas desse site, mas não tive sucesso.

Código:

```
package tabelas;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Tabelas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        JFrame j = new JFrame("Bora mecao");
        j.setBounds(0,0,400,400);

        JTable tabela = new JTable();
        tabela.setBounds(10,10,200,200);

        j.add(tabela);

        String[] colunas = {"Marca", "Local"};

        DefaultTableModel modelo = (new DefaultTableModel(){
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
                return false;
            }
        });

        modelo.setColumnIdentifiers(colunas);
        modelo.setRowCount(0);

        Object[] objetos = new Object[2];
        objetos[0] = "LG";
        objetos[1] = "Chalé";
        modelo.addRow(objetos);

        tabela.setModel(modelo);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tabela);
        contentPane.add(scroll);

        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        j.setLayout(null);
        j.setVisible(true);        

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro segue uma sugestão quanto a usar layout absoluto:

> **Evite usar layout absoluto, a não ser que seja de extrema necessidade e que saiba as consequências disso**, pois layout absoluto dificulta manutenção da interface e faz com que sua aplicação fique com aparência diferente dependendo do monitor e resolução que estiver sendo executada.
>
> Existem vários [**gerenciadores de layouts**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) para que você não tenha que se preocupar com posicionamento ou organização manual de componentes. Sem contar que o uso de layouts faz com que seu código fique mais fácil de dar manutenção do que ficar inserindo um monte de `setbounds`, e caso precise alterar a posição de algum componente, no layout absoluto, vai ter que reposicionar todos manualmente.

Apenas removendo a linha abaixo o código, teoricamente, funcionaria:

```
j.setLayout(null);
```

Mas você tambem adiciona a tabela direto no `JFrame`, e mais abaixo no código, adiciona num `JScrollPane`. Remova a adição direta no `JFrame` e a definiçao de tamanho usando o `setBounds`, pois como voce mesmo já pesquisou aqui, tabelas precisam ser adicionadas em componente "rolaveis" para que sejam exibidas corretamente. Se quiser controlar o tamanho da tabela na tela, veja os links do aviso acima relativo a *Layout Managers* ou veja exemplos aqui mesmo no site através [**deste link**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing+layout).

Outra coisa que precisa ser atentado é você não iniciar a interface dentro da thread correta. Interfaces feitas com a API swing são [despachadas para uma thread específica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/28595), e fazer operações fora deste laço para controlar a tela poderá ocorrer problemas de concorrência de threads, já que o método main executa em uma thread diferente.

E para adicionar linhas usando `DefaultTableModel` você precisa passar um array de uma dimensao que representará as colunas e outro array de arrays, onde os arrays internos representam as linhas a serem preenchidas. Recomendo a leitura deste tópico: [Como faço para popular um JTable?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20738/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-popular-um-jtable)

Com as correções, o código fica assim:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Tabelas {

    public Tabelas() {

        JFrame j = new JFrame("Bora mecao");
        j.setSize(400,400);

        JTable tabela = new JTable();      

        String[] colunas = {"Marca", "Local"};
        String[][] objetos = {{"LG", "chalé"}};

        DefaultTableModel modelo = (new DefaultTableModel(objetos, colunas){
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
                return false;
            }
        });

        tabela.setModel(modelo);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tabela);
        j.getContentPane().add(scroll);

        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        j.setVisible(true);  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Tabelas());;
    }
}
```

O resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda de todos!